# What is the name for the little numbers that appear over characters' heads when they lose health?

Tags: gui, interface, glossary, terminology

...you know the ones. Something like "value overlays" or "value pop-ups" describes them quite well, but I was thinking they might have a real name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Floating text" does it for me.  That's what I've always called it, although I've never used it specifically for indicating damage done.  My usage was usually to indicate where something important in the scene was (e.g. "retrieve this data disk").

Answer (score 7):

In WoW terms the most popular addon is called Scrolling Combat Text, which I think describes it pretty well.

When I've written my own implementations I use the more general "Floating Game Text".

Answer (score 7):

I think our term was "Damage floaters".

Comment: "Damage float(er)s" for damage and combat-related text (e.g. "Dodge!" "Critical!"). "Reticle" for the other stuff around a mob, e.g. name and health bar. "Floating/floater text" (by the design team) or "notifications" (in code) for the stuff that pops into the middle of the screen in a similar way.

Comment: (Wait, "was"? If Alex already rewrote that he'd better explain. :)

Comment: Past tense for me since I don't have to care anymore :-P

Comment: "Damage Floaters" sounds like the morning after a rather hot curry.

Comment: In every options menu I've ever seen, it's been called "Damage numbers". I've never once heard them called "floaters"