# What is the specific name of this UI component?

Tags: gui, terminology

Is there a specific name for this kind of ui component? Sometimes it only renders a symbol (without text) so using name like `TextComponent` is imo not very fitting.

[image]

Comment: FloatingTextElement?

Comment: Generally attributed to window UI structures, [*modal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window) may be similar. Not sure if there is an exact name for just smaller UI elements though.

Comment: @lozzajp, `modal` is not relevant because the element does not represents a UI window.

Comment: @KevinLaw windowless modal window with text? I think they are just called floating text, I had a google around for Final Fantasy terms and that seems to be the norm (or floating damage numbers etc.).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the name for the little numbers that appear over characters' heads when they lose health?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3173/what-is-the-name-for-the-little-numbers-that-appear-over-characters-heads-when)

Answer (score 6):

Not formally, but I usually see them referred to as "damage floaters." In the occasions where they do not actually convey damage, they're usually called "*some other kind of* floater," or just "floaters."

- https://forums.wildstar-online.com/forums/index.php?/topic/30733-is-it-possible-to-disable-damage-floaters/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/sto/comments/3ign3n/stos_abysmal_fpskilling_ui_what_do_we_do/
- https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/game/gw2/UI-options

Et cetera. You can find several other references via Google searches (I'd recommend you include the term "UI" in the search though; otherwise you tend to get a lot of results about retina detatchment and such, which are decidedly unrelated).

Comment: I really like "Floaters". Short, evocative, and unused.